# Notation in Huybrechts' $A\wedge A$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, notation, complex-geometry

When introducing curvature (p.183), Huybrechts uses a notation which I don't really understand: For example in the formulas
$$F_{\nabla}=d(A)+A\wedge A, $$
$$dF_\nabla = F_\nabla \wedge A - A\wedge F_\nabla.$$
What does "$\wedge$" stand for? It doesn't seem to be the usual exterior product, because from the way the formulas are written, "$\wedge$" doesn't seem to be skew-symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Andrew's explanation, $\wedge$'s therein are not only exterior products, but also respective algebraic arithmetic. Here are two examples.

Suppose $A$ is a usual $1$-form, e.g., $A=\omega$. Then $A\wedge A=\omega\wedge\omega=0$ follows the usual exterior product.

Suppose $A$ is a matrix $1$-form, e.g.,
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\omega_{11}&\omega_{12}\\
\omega_{21}&\omega_{22}
\end{array}
\right),
$$
where each $\omega_{ij}$ is a usual $1$-form. Then
$$
A\wedge A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\omega_{11}&\omega_{12}\\
\omega_{21}&\omega_{22}
\end{array}
\right)\wedge\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\omega_{11}&\omega_{12}\\
\omega_{21}&\omega_{22}
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\omega_{11}\wedge\omega_{11}+\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_{21}&\omega_{11}\wedge\omega_{12}+\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_{22}\\
\omega_{21}\wedge\omega_{11}+\omega_{22}\wedge\omega_{21}&\omega_{21}\wedge\omega_{12}+\omega_{22}\wedge\omega_{22}\end{array}
\right),
$$
where $\wedge$ not only includes the usual exterior product, but also the matrix-matrix multiplication.

Comment: what about the terms $\omega_{ii} \wedge \omega_{ii}$ in the resulting formula?

Comment: @klirk: They would vanish (reduce to zero as usual exterior products). I left them there as I hoped to make it clear that it preserves matrix-matrix multiplication.

Comment: @klirk: Also, should $A$ be a matrix $1$-form, ${\rm d}A$ is defined entry-wise, i.e.,$${\rm d}A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{\rm d}\omega_{11}&{\rm d}\omega_{12}\\{\rm d}\omega_{21}&{\rm d}\omega_{22}\end{array}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

The wedge here indicates the combination of wedge product on forms and composition of the endomorphisms. So, if we have $A= \sum_i \phi_i\otimes a_i$ and $B=\sum_j \psi_j \otimes b_j$, where $\phi_i,\psi_j$ are forms and $a_i,b_j$ are endomorphisms, then
$$
 A\wedge B = \sum_{i,j} (\psi_i\wedge \phi_j) \otimes (a_i\circ b_j)
$$

Huybrechts mentions this in the middle of page 183, but it didn't fill in this detail.

Comment: so if $A=\phi \otimes a$, then $A\wedge A=0$?

Comment: That is correct.